# Loop array in array

Tags: php, arrays

Which loop can I use for  an array in array with the output like this:

```
Coffee 1,90 | 2,30
Tea 1,70 | 2,20
```

This is the array

```
<?php
Array ( [coffee] => Array ( 
                    [Small] => 1,90
                    [Big] => 2,30
                ) 
    [tea] => Array ( 
                    [Small] => 1,70 
                    [Big] => 2,20 
                )
)
?>
```

I tried this

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $beverage => $types) {
    echo $beverage;
  foreach ($types as $type => $price) {
    echo $price;
  }
}
?>
```

But the output displays this

```
coffee 1,902,30
tea 1,702,20
```

How can I separate this like

```
Coffee 1,90 | 2,30
Tea 1,70 | 2,20
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($array as $beverage => $types) {
    echo ucfirst($beverage) . implode(' | ', $types);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $beverage => $types) {
    echo $beverage;
    foreach ($types as $type => $price) {
        if ($price == end($types)) {

            echo $price."|";
        }
        else{
            echo $price;
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-end-function/